# How was Luke's prosthetic hand in Episode V filmed?

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes, the-empire-strikes-back, props

I am referring to [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6-llUSPwaY?t=0m37s) (starting at the 0m37s mark) in *Star Wars, Episode V: The Empire Strikes Back*.

This seems like a very sophisticated prop glove, but there is significant visible depth to the "cavity".

**How was this filmed?**

[image]

Comment: Are we absolutely certain the prosthetic hand is a prop? I've heard Mark Hamill is a method actor . . .

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can see the original prop [here](https://www.flickriver.com/photos/mattandkristy/3474627810/). Note that the metal collar has slipped down slightly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The actor would sit under the table and reach up through a hole, then place their hand flat onto the table. The prop would then be slid into position flush against their hand, covering the hole and creating the illusion that it was their real arm.

[image]

Comment: Looking at the 2nd pic, it's entirely possible Mark was able to simply put his arm through the prop, like a gauntlet. I'm not discounting the "hole in the desk" option, since that was widely used, but rather offering another plausible theory. The opening looks really shallow in the first pic and simply raising the lip of the "skin" on the wrist end would give it depth from the filmed camera angle. Unfortunately, that skin is hidden on the side view so we can't really see if that's the case.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that his hand went through the cast as you propose @computercarguy - remember the arm is shown with moving parts and gears and stuff, that opening was probably the housing for all the mechanisms and mechanics used to operate the robot guts

Comment: All the GIFs and video clips I can see show actuators moving when his fingers move, which is different from the wires and resistors in the prop you have pictured. I wonder if that's a difference between the Original and Remastered versions? Is there another prop arm somewhere?

Comment: @computercarguy I suspect that (most of) the actual innards of the prop were damaged and/or discarded after filming, and the current innards were a crude attempt to recreate the look of the original for display purposes.

Comment: All this time I thought it was a form of greenscreen. Welp, thanks.

Comment: @computercarguy It looks to me like the prop structure is provided by woven galvanized steel ground straps or similar. (see last and second-last photos) These are very poky at the best of times, and in this case look to have been left as a ragged edge by whatever cutting method was used. I think this would be a very uncomfortable place to put one's arm, even if it did fit under the simulated opening.

Comment: @jkf, I seriously doubt that "pokey bits" is enough for a young actor to refuse to use a prop. As beat up and damaged as it is, those wires could easily have become "pokey" years after the scene was shot. And why would a prop maker go through all the trouble of making and reinforcing a hollow prop if the actor wasn't intended to wear it? I don't think a determination of the correct method of filming can be discovered simply by looking at this prop, as it doesn't fully explain anything. I'd like to hear what Mr. Hamill has to say about it, get the answer directly from someone who knows.

Answer (score 56):

If you look closely at the slope of the back of Mark Hamill's hand, you can see that it seems to turn a bit more toward the vertical as it approaches the metal clamp on his wrist.  In fact, Hamill is reaching up through the table, with the heel of his hand pressed against the end of a a fake arm.  Everything to the right of the metal clamp ring is a fake limb; the robotics are embedded in a completely fake lower arm segment.  Notice how the texture of the actor's real skin on the hand and the fake skin above the clamp are quite different (although, in universe, that could be attributed to Luke's traumatic injury).

[image: Hand prosthesis]

Note that Hamill's upper body is never in the shot while the arm panel is open.  After the droid 2-1B closes the panel, it immediately cuts to Hamill sitting down, with his arm free of the restraints.  It is a really well done shot, and I remember when I first saw the movie as a young child, the coolness of seeing Luke's new hand almost helped me overcome my horror that they had not managed to rescue Han Solo at the end of the film.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation. While I am upvoting your response, I am marking @Valorum's response as the answer because they hunted down the actual prop, laying bare the mechanism.

Comment: @ElleFie to me the innards of the alleged prop shown don't look anything like what was visible in the movie shots.   In the movie there are clearly lots of parallel linear actuators, whereas the photos above look massively jumbled and include lots of very obvious 20th century resistors and diodes.   To me that prop looks fake.

Comment: @Alnitak I agree about the insides, but everything about the outside surface and clamps looks right. I wonder if it's a case of the piece being modified and recycled for another film.

Comment: @Alnitak - That prop is from the Lucasfilm Archives Tour

Comment: @Valorum that may be so, but it's not as shown in the movie.

Comment: @Alnitak - Don't forget that it's quite elderly. Props are usually intended to last the length of time it takes to film them, so colours will have faded and the innards may well be one of *several* sets.

Comment: Yea, looks like the prop has lost some parts. In the film screenshots you also see a row of red LEDs that aren't visible in the prop.

Comment: Thanks for posting the clip - and now we all have to wait 3 whole years until we find out if Chewie & Lando find Han Solo! :-)

Comment: Not saying they did, but it would of course be possible for another person under the table to provide the hand.

Comment: @RobertF there's also parts in the photo that aren't visible in the movie, especially the diodes and resistors that I can't believe any competent prop designer would have used.   They're far too recognisable as "1970's Earth".

Comment: It's  possible that the actuator rods were added using the matte process and  animated to synchronise with the already filmed finger movements. having the arm clamped down greatly helps in filming this effect. In such a case the actual content of the prosthetic would not appear on screen. (being replaced with the matte content) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matte_(filmmaking)